# Get Result of document.querySelectorAll in PuppeteerSharp

Tags: c#, webautomation, puppeteer-sharp

Here is my simple code:

```
var element = await page.EvaluateExpressionAsync($"document.querySelectorAll('[{attributeName}=\"{attributeValue}\"]')[0];");
```

it will work correctly on the page, but it returns `null`. where is the problem? I know it will execute correctly but I can not detect it on code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get an element from the browser you should get an `ElementHandle`, which is a pointer to an element in the browser, using `EvaluateExpressionHandleAsync`:

```
var element = await page.EvaluateExpressionHandleAsync($"document.querySelectorAll('[{attributeName}=\"{attributeValue}\"]')[0];");
```